# Curl with Loop using php

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem, I want to get data from another website and display it on my website using cURL.

For example, this is data from the other website which I would like to parse and display on my website.

```
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 1</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 2</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 3</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 4</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 5</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 6</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 7</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 8</a></div>
```

Currently I'm getting first row of data, but now I want to get all of this data.
I have tried this so far:

```
$curl = curl_init('www.domain.com/search.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="users-name">(.*?)<\/div>/s';

if(preg_match($regex, $page, $list))
    print_r($list[0]);
else
    print "Not found";
```

Comment: What do you mean? You are explicitly calling first match in the list with ``print_r($list[0]);``

Comment: If you change `print_r($list[0]);` to `print_r($list);` you should see the entire contents of the array. It should contain the other matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
preg_match($regex, $page, $list)
```

with

```
preg_match_all($regex, $page, $list)
```

preg_match stops after the first match.
preg_match_all gets *all* the matches.

Comment: @user3487256 in StackOverflow if you find answer correct please vote up and accept it as correct answer.

Comment: i have one more problem, can i get more than one div in one time. for example: <div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 1</a></div> i'm getting all this now i also want user address. its another div <div class="users-name-address"> <a href='#'>users 1 address</a></div>